# HashMap hang in concurrent access

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, hashmap, java-7

We have an application that used an instance of a `java.util.HashMap` that is - through various indirections - shared so that multiple threads access it concurrently. We fixed this by now, as we know that `java.util.HashMap` is not thread safe and shouldn't be accessed concurrently.

Before that fix, and the reason we found out, we had an upgrade of the JDK (to IBM JDK 7 SR3) and *after* that upgrade we experienced occasional hangs during get operations of that HashMap instance (the hang occurs in the `getEntry()` method.)

Out of curiosity, I'd like to know, what happens inside the HashMap, that is causing the hang. What is the difference in the implementation that is affecting the behavior in concurrent access?

Regarding the HashMap implementation it appears, the IBM JDK is the same as the Oracle JDK and the OpenJDK, which is again different than the Java8 version (using a `Node` datastructure).

I believe, the [difference between java7u40 b43 vs b147](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/util/HashMap.java/?v=diff&id2=7-b147#906) represents the change that was introduced with the upgrade.

My current assumption is, the cause for the hang is related to the change in the `addEntry` method, changing from *add-first-resize-after* to *resize-first-add-after*.

But does anyone has an exact understanding, what is exactly going on during concurrent access?

Comment: Data races are by their very definition unpredictable and random. The change to the JDK might have been a slight change somewhere entirely unrelated that caused some process to take a nanosecond longer, exasperating the problem. It is more than likely the issue what there all along, but went from a one in a few million chance to one in a few thousand. Without recreating the issue and taking a thread dump, it is almost certainly impossible to determine the cause. Thread safety cannot be proven by testing, but only by careful analysis of the code.

Comment: There are no `getEntry()` and `addEntry()` methods in `HashMap`. Are you sure it's there that you get the hang?

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire there are internally.

Comment: @BoristheSpider My mistake then.

Comment: we could actually wrote a unit test doing concurrent puts on a HashMap which could reproduce the issue quite reliably. All threads get stuck while iterating over the linked lists of the buckets, either during put or transfer. And I run the tests against both old jdk7 impl, new jdk7 impl and jdk8 impl, all get stuck.

Comment: could it possibly be, that it creates a linked list whith an entry pointing to itself as *next*?

Comment: Absolutely anything is possible - without memory barriers threads will see different versions of the same data (no visibility guarantee) and will do partial updates to that data (no atomicity guarantees). Even operations as innocuous as `i++` stop working as expected. I assure you, you are barking up with wrong tree trying to work out why it doesn't work. Just take it for granted that it doesn't and never did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up debugging the unit test we wrote and inspecting the buckets of the HashMap when the thread hangs/loops. And indeed, they create a cycle in the bucket when two threads concurrently resize the map. It ends up with a structure like this:

```
bucket1[0].entry1.next = entry2;
bucket1[0].entry2.next = entry1;
```

A more detailed explanation can be found here [Resizing the HashMap: dangers ahead](https://plumbr.eu/blog/java/resizing-the-hashmap-dangers-ahead?utm_content=bufferf8e97&utm_medium=social&utm_source=twitter.com&utm_campaign=buffer)

Answer (score 1):

When a *hashmap.put(key, value)* is invoked, the HashMap threshold is checked. If the map size exceeds this threshold, the map will be resized and all the entries will be rehashed. 
In a multi-threaded environment this will leave your HashMap in an inconsistent state. In the least, you should safeguard the calls in your application that write to the HashMap by using synchronization or locks.
I recommend using java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.